# [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray

I have use `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]`. So i need to set my viewcontroller in `NSArray`. But i tried below method, then i'm getting error. I understood i don't have array of 2. So, how can i set the viewcontroller in array and make as rootviewcontroller.

```
ARimageViewController *arimage = [[ARimageViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:arimage];

SampleViewController *sample = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sample];

SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav,nav1,nav2, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;        
self.window.rootViewController = nav1; 
self.window.rootViewController = nav2;
```

PushViewcontroller:

SettingViewcontroller:

```
SettingsViewController *set=[[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:set animated:YES];
```

Back to pushviewcontroller:

```
Class vcClass = NSClassFromString(self.appViewControllerClassName);
id vc = [[vcClass alloc]  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you describe it from a user/usage point of view?

Comment: Your problem is that you push the view controller the wrong way on the navigationcontroller stack. Remove the 'self.window.rootViewController' and replace them with '[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];' or similar.

Comment: are you trying to use a UITabBarController?

Comment: I have 4 viewcontroller. When i go from 1st to 2nd viewcontroller and 2nd to 3rd viewcontroller it's working. then comeback to 1st viewcontroller or 2nd viewcontroller then click the button the pushviewcontroller is not working. SO that i'm trying to achieve objectArIndex

Comment: You first read UIViewController Programming guide.

Comment: Where are you pushing view controllers?

Comment: Ok so where are you trying to use `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]` and for what?

Comment: In sampleViewcontroller when i click the button it redirect to SettingsviewController and in settingviewcontroller click back button i need to redirect sampleViewcontroller.

Comment: Can anyone help this?